# How to update table using the Dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

IN the following code sample, I want to update the table but it's not. it is Updating my datagrid. I want the description to be 'Care' on the table. This is just a sample project to learn how to use the datasets.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSetPK ds;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=ORDERS;uid=OG;pwd=OG;database=PRO2");
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [OG].[TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES]", cn);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   // dsProducts tds = new dsProducts();
    ds = new DataSetPK();

    da.Fill(ds, ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.TableName);

    dgok.DataSource = ds;
    dgok.DataBind();

   }
    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    DataRow row = null;
   // DataSetPK ds = new DataSetPK();
    row = ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.NewTAP_C_ROOM_TABLESRow();
    row[0] = "T1";
    row[1] = "a";

    row[2] = "test";
    ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.BeginInit();
    ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.Rows.Add(row);
    ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.EndInit();
    ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.AcceptChanges();
    ds.AcceptChanges();

    da.Update(ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES);

    da.Update(ds, ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.TableName);


    dgok.DataSource = ds;
    dgok.DataBind();


    }
   protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.Rows[0][2]="Care";
    ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.AcceptChanges();
    ds.AcceptChanges();
    da.Update(ds, ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.TableName);

    dgok.DataSource = ds;
    dgok.DataBind();

    }
   }
```

Comment: Accept some of your questions. You accept a question by clicking the tjek symbol on one of the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the table, you will have to run the SQL query for it.

And if you are using SQL server, I think the SQL command to rename a column would be

```
 sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: I am more interesting in updating the data. here for example, why this does not work?   da.Update(ds, ds.TAP_C_ROOM_TABLES.TableName);

Comment: You need to add an update command 

          string upd = @"update employee set firstname = @firstname where id = @id";
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(upd, cn);
           da.UpdateCommand = cmd;

And then you run the da.Update(ds, ds.tablename);

Comment: This should help you out      http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UpdatetableusingSqlDataAdapter.htm